# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que PDO inserte los string vacíos como nulos en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Tengo la siguiente tabla:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Campo` smallint(4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

En MySQL `NULL = DEFAULT NULL`.

Estoy cargando un fichero .SQL que internamente contiene una o varias líneas LOAD FILE, entonces tengo el siguiente código para cargar los datos en base de datos.

```
$queries = explode(";", file_get_contents($mySQLFile));
foreach($queries as $q)
{
 if($query != '')
 {
  $s= $pdo->prepare($q);
  $s->execute();
 }
}
```

Mi CSV contiene `""` en la columa `Campo`, pero yo he configurado PDO con la siguiente línea `PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` que, supuestamente, agrega NULL cuando detecta un string vacío.

**Resultado:**
En la columna `Campo` se agrega un `0` ¿Por qué PDO inserta 0 en vez de NULL? ¿Qué puedo hacer que no sea editar todas las líneas LOAD FILE, ver que columnas aceptan nulos y hacer `col = nullif(@col, '');` ya que, esto me llevaría un montón de horas de trabajo, me gustaría encontrar una solución más automática.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo estas creando tu conexión a PDO, incluyendo los atributos que le estás pasando, sea en la misma conexión o posteriormente, pulsando en [edit]? Recuerda no publicar tus credenciales reales de conexión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

Reemplazar los string vacíos **""** por **\N** en los ficheros CSV.

MySQL interpreta **\N** como nulls.